# Difference between "direct code" and making a certain "function" in R code

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I'm crazing to confuse what I do.

It is not important the detail in the code, and I have two options

First one:

```
 ggplot(dta_fin, aes(x=PVT_0610_Z, y=PVT_1115_Z)) +
      geom_point(shape=1) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
      geom_smooth(method='lm') +
      facet_wrap(~ GROUP, scales="fixed", ncol=3)
```

Second one used by function in R:

```
aFunction <-function(dataname,xx,yy)
      {
        ggplot(dataname, aes(x=xx, y=yy)) +
          geom_point(shape=1) +
          geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
          geom_smooth(method='lm') +
          facet_wrap(~ GROUP, scales="fixed", ncol=3)
      }

      aFunction(dta_fin,PVT_0610_Z,PVT_1115_Z)
```

It is natural to get same graph from First and Second one, but I have different figure from the two code. What is the reason??..........

Comment: Can you provide some data and a minimal example so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: use `aes_string` inside the function, and pass in the column names using strings instead of bare names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should aes_string() when calling ggplot from inside a function:

```
aFunction <-function(dataname,xx,yy)
      {
        ggplot(dataname, aes_string(x=xx, y=yy)) +
          geom_point(shape=1) +
          geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="dashed") +
          geom_smooth(method='lm') +
          facet_wrap(~ GROUP, scales="fixed", ncol=3)
      }
```

Do not forget to pass the xx and yy as strings to the functions inside:

```
  aFunction(dta_fin,PVT_0610_Z,PVT_1115_Z)
```